# How to setup my KorGE project to use Fleks ECS library?

Tags: kotlin, game-engine, game-development, korge

I want to use [Fleks ECS](https://github.com/Quillraven/Fleks) as shown in this example:
https://github.com/korlibs/korge-next/tree/main/samples/fleks-ecs

How to setup my KorGE project to be able to import the Fleks library?

Answer (score 2):

I found that there is a built in function to import the Fleks into KorGE project.

Just configure the `build.gradle.kts` file as in the example below:

```
...
korge {
    id = "com.example.mygame"
    name = "My Game"

    supportFleks()

    targetJvm()
    targetJs()
    targetDesktop()
    targetIos()
    targetAndroidIndirect() // targetAndroidDirect()
}
```